# Test VB.Net Application as if Vb were not installed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a VB.Net application that I plan to distribute using the .exe file in the Release folder. Upon sending this to a user, I was informed that it would not run on their system. The exe runs fine on my system no matter the location of the file so it's not a folder dependency. I don't have easy access to another computer, so is there an easy way to test my file as if visual basic were not installed on my system?

Edit: By "does not run" I mean nothing occurs when the exe is clicked

Comment: create a VM without the relevant .NET version installed would be the easiest way. Might make sense to collect the exact error message from the user as well. "does not run" is a bit vague.

Comment: Once I got a "application does not run" comment and it was a button that didn't do what they expected it to do.

Comment: If it's a dependency issue, going to the build menu and then Publish, versus just copying the .EXE - may resolve this for you.  It's been a bit, but this puts it in a nice package

Comment: Doesn't run is actually exactly what happens as when you click the executable nothing at all occurs. No Error, no nothing. (I edited the post to reflect this)

I looked into publishing, but that packs it into a setup and unfortunately the application needs to be run on a system where the user will not have admin privileges and will not be able to run an install

Comment: I will look into the VM option though, thank you

Comment: ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the application.